# Is it possible to use an Xbox One controller battery pack in an Xbox 360 Controller?

Tags: xbox-360, controllers, xbox-one

I am looking into buying an Xbox One and I want to know if I can use my Xbox 360's charging dock for the new controllers. Is this possible?

Comment: *battery                   Whoops

Answer (score 3):

Simply, you cannot. The battery packs in the xbox one's controller and the 360's controller are shaped very differently and are not compatible with each other.